# Como enviar un parametro de un form a método show en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

soy nuevo en laravel y quisiera saber como pasar un parámetro desde el siguiente form, para que lo reciba el método show del controlador.

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => array('products.show), 'method' => 'get']) }}
    {!! Form::text('id', null, [ 'class' => 'form-control' ]) !!} 
    {!! Form::submit('Mostrar',['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

El código del controlador lo copié de un tutorial que estaba siguiendo y funciona bien. Lo que quiero es como enviar el campo ingresado en el form hacia el método "show($id)".

El metodo es el siguiente:

```
public function show($id) {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    return view('products.show', compact('product'));
}
```

Rutas : `Route::resource('products','ProductController');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo haces en la definición de la ruta por medio de la cual se llega a dicho método de un controlador.

Si estás en Laravel 5.4, es en el archivo routes/web.php

Sería algo más o menos así, asumiendo que recibas dicho parámetro por medio de GET:

```
Route::get('mostrar/{id}', 'myController@show');
```

Debes tener en cuenta que necesitas probablemente incluir middlewares a algunas o todas tus rutas, como lo es el popular middleware web, toda esta información la encuentras en la documentación de Laravel.

---

**Edición después de explicación**:

Para poder usar un input y luego pasar dicho valor a la URL, la única forma de hacerlo es por medio de JavaScript.

Voy a plantear una solución rápida con jQuery (con el perdón de los que saben mucho más de JavaScript), la cual no es la mejor, pero la tengo "a la mano":

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['products.show', 'PROD_ID'], 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => 'form_show']) }}
{!! Form::text('id', null, [ 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'field_id']) !!}
```

En cuanto a jQuery, sería algo así:

```
let myForm = $('#form_show');
myForm.submit(function(e) {

  if ($('#field_id).val() != '') {
     myForm.attr('action').replace('PROD_ID', $('#field_id').val());
  } else {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('Campo vacío');
  }

});
```

Comment: Hola tal vez no me expliqué bien. Seguí un tutorial en internet del cuál copié los métodos, rutas, etc me funciona todo bien. El caso es que yo quiero agregar un formulario que busca por "id" para que al ingresar un valor, ese valla al método "show($id)", pero no se como enviar ese valor desde el form.

Comment: Si pretendes usar el método `show($id)` de esa forma, la única forma por la que puedes pasar el dato es por la URL, asumiendo que lo desees hacer con un input, deberás pasarlo por JavaScript a la URL del formulario. Voy a proponerte una solución rápida entonces.